# Spring Boot deployment fails with StackoverflowError in Weblogic 10.3.4.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic

I have been developing a Spring Boot application (with latest version). I had to run it under Weblogic - Servlet 2.5 and I made the necessary changes mentioned in the documentation. `http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file-for-older-containers`

Application and Weblogic both uses Java 7.

I was deploying and running it normally for a few days but now I am getting the below error:

```
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101371> <There was a failure when processing annotations for application /wle/bea/user_projects/some_place/servers/BNETM1/stage/app_name/app_name.war. Please make sure that the annotations are valid. The error is >
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'app_name.war'>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:393)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:613)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:184)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:207)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader.findClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:101)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.contribute(WebComponentContributor.java:160)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.jee.server.Bootstrap.deploy(Bootstrap.java:217)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.jee.spi.WLSBootstrap.deploy(WLSBootstrap.java:116)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.jee.server.Bootstrap.deploy(Bootstrap.java:153)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.jee.spi.WebComponentContributorBrokerImpl.initialize(WebComponentContributorBrokerImpl.java:45)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.initialize(WebComponentContributor.java:98)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processAnnotations(WebAppServletContext.java:1386)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Notice> <StdErr> <BEA-000000> <at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:449)>
<Jul 31, 2015 12:34:10 PM GST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1438331647630' for task '259'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'app_name.war''
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'app_name.war'
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:393)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

you can exclude slf4j jars in pom.xml, when I encountered the same problem was solved in this way;

```
<exclusion>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
</exclusion>
```

When these types of dependencies conflicted you can get this type of error